# Stand-alone angular module with web worker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, web-worker

I am looking to build a standalone angular js module that makes use of web workers for some heavier processing. This module will be used by another angular web application that I'm building and potentially others.

I want this module to be installable through bower with the web worker scripts packaged in. The problem is that the web worker scripts need to be external files (unless you use the Blob/Url technique, but my understanding is that it's not supported by IE). I don't want the client application using this module to have to put the worker scripts in a public directory or anything like that. I want them to include my module and have everything just work.

In short: I'd like my web worker scripts packaged within an angular js module. I need to support IE 10+ and cannot use the Blob/URL technique.

Comment: could you be more vague... what is it you are ultimately asking?

Comment: You can only execute a script through a URL for a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker). So without the use of `createObjectUrl` it isn't possible. You should use graceful degeneration to fallback to functioning without the use of web workers. Alternatively you can host the worker script on a CDN and customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

for those who still interested: take a look at https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread plugin, 
which allows you to execute a function in a separate thread.

Function can be defined directly in the main thread or called from an external javascript file.

Function can be:

- Regular functions
- Object's methods
- Functions with dependencies
- Functions with context
- Anonymous functions

Documentation and examples can be found at http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/

--Vadim